# AutoMapper strings to enum descriptions

Tags: enums, automapper, valueinjecter

Given the requirement:

Take an object graph, set all enum type properties based on the **processed** value of a second string property. Convention dictates that the name of the source string property will be that of the enum property with a postfix of "Raw".

By processed we mean we'll need to strip specified characters e.t.c.

I've looked at custom formatters, value resolvers and type converters, none of which seems like a solution for this?

We want to use AutoMapper as opposed to our own reflection routine for two reasons, a) it's used extensively throughout the rest of the project and b) it gives you recursive traversal ootb.

--  Example  --

Given the (simple) structure below, and this:

```
var tmp = new SimpleClass 
  { 
       CountryRaw = "United States",
       Person = new Person { GenderRaw="Male" }
  };

var tmp2 = new SimpleClass();

Mapper.Map(tmp, tmp2);
```

we'd expect tmp2's MappedCountry enum to be Country.UnitedStates and the Person property to have a gender of Gender.Male.

```
public class SimpleClass1
{
  public string CountryRaw {get;set;}

  public Country MappedCountry {get;set;}

  public Person Person {get;set;}
}

public class Person
{
  public string GenderRaw {get;set;}

  public Gender Gender {get;set;}

  public string Surname {get;set;}
}

public enum Country
{
  UnitedStates = 1,
  NewZealand = 2
}

public enum Gender
{
  Male,
  Female,
  Unknown
}
```

Thanks

Comment: could you show an example of what you have and to what you want to map it

Comment: Sure, edited original post :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it with the [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/),
here is the whole thing:

I've added one more prop to the SimpleClass just to show you how it works

```
public class SixFootUnderTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var o = new SimpleClass1
                    {
                        CountryRaw = "United States",
                        GenderRaw = "Female",
                        Person = new Person { GenderRaw = "Male" }
                    };

        var oo = new SimpleClass1();

        oo.InjectFrom(o)
            .InjectFrom<StrRawToEnum>(o);
        oo.Person.InjectFrom<StrRawToEnum>(o.Person);

        oo.Country.IsEqualTo(Country.UnitedStates);
        oo.Gender.IsEqualTo(Gender.Female);
        oo.Person.Gender.IsEqualTo(Gender.Male);
    }

    public class SimpleClass1
    {
        public string CountryRaw { get; set; }

        public Country Country { get; set; }

        public string GenderRaw { get; set; }

        public Gender Gender { get; set; }

        public Person Person { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string GenderRaw { get; set; }

        public Gender Gender { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }


    public class StrRawToEnum : LoopValueInjection
    {
        protected override bool UseSourceProp(string sourcePropName)
        {
            return sourcePropName.EndsWith("Raw");
        }

        protected override string TargetPropName(string sourcePropName)
        {
            return sourcePropName.RemoveSuffix("Raw");
        }

        protected override bool TypesMatch(Type sourceType, Type targetType)
        {
            return sourceType == typeof(string) && targetType.IsEnum;
        }

        protected override object SetValue(object sourcePropertyValue)
        {
            return Enum.Parse(TargetPropType, sourcePropertyValue.ToString().Replace(" ", ""), true);
        }
    }

    public enum Country
    {
        UnitedStates = 1,
        NewZealand = 2
    }


    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female,
        Unknown
    }
}
```

also in case you need to do it from CountryRaw to MappedCountry
you could do it like this:

```
oo.InjectFrom(new StrRawToEnum().TargetPrefix("Mapped"), o);
```

Comment: This, my friend, is a very clean solution! Thanks :-).